# UV Faces Proportionally Incorrect After Unwrap

Tags: uv

This is more of an annoyance than anything else but it's bugging me.  I have a simple object that when unwrapped, has a disproportional UV map.  I've tried everything that I can think of such as:
Merging duplicate vertices - none
Triangulation mesh
Limited resolve
Chopping up the corner areas into individual faces
Removed and replaced the back face
Recalculating normals
A bunch of other stuff that I can't remember

What am I missing?

The object has narrower faces at the bevels but the UV has every face at a consistent width:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). You have multiple unwrapping options available. Simply toggling Angle-based/Conformal could help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jachym was correct.  Selecting the Conformal method in the UV options solved it.

[image]

[image]